# LookupError: No installed app with label 'user'

Tags: python, django

I am receiving `LookupError: No installed app with label 'user'` when running the following code:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser,
            **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('El email debe de ser obligatorio')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, is_activate=True,
                is_staff=is_staff, is_superuser=is_superuser, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self.db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None,
            **extra_fields):    
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password,
            **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.URLField()


    objects = UserManager()

    is_activate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRE_FIELDS = ['email']

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

The source of the error is not readily apparent, why is this error being presented?

In particular, which line is looking for the 'user' label, and why is it not finding what it is looking for?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: No, please post it in your question, properly formatted.

Comment: What is the value of your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py to the custom User model

and also include the app that has the custom user model to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

in settings verify that:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'you_app_name.User'
```

and in installed apps add:

```
'your_app_name.apps.UsersConfig',
```